# Is there a zsh equivalent of bash builtin readarray?

Tags: bash, zsh

I recently became aware of `readarray` in Bash v5.  Is there an equivalent for zsh?

Comment: Related: https://www.reddit.com/r/zsh/comments/tt6gm8/why_doesnt_zsh_have_an_equivalent_of_bashs/

Comment: Thanks, I found that later on too. also this... https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In zsh there's no builtin `readarray` command, however it does have a one line expression which achieves the basic syntax of `readarray -t`.

```
myarray=("${(@f)$(< myfile)}")
```

To use `stdin` instead of a regular file, we need to use `cat`:

```
myarray=("${(@f)$(cat)}")
```

For capturing output from a command, you can also use:

```
myarray=("${(@f)$(command)}")
```

In all the examples, empty lines (except trailing ones that are trimmed by command substitution) are included in the array too.   If you don't want to keep empty lines, change it to:

```
myarray=(${(f)"$(< myfile)"})
myarray=(${(f)"$(cat)"})
myarray=(${(f)"$(command)"})
```

`f` (for line `f`eed) is in fact short for  `ps[\n]`, `s[sep]` being to split on arbitrary separator, `p` allowing escape sequences like `\n` or `\0` and parameter expansions in `sep`. See also `0` as a shortcut for `ps[\0]`.

So the `readarray -rd '' array` of bash 4.4+ can be written `array=( "${(@0)$(cat)}" )`.

There's an important difference though. For `readarray`, `-d` specifies a `d`elimiter, while the `s` parameter expansion flag takes a `s`eparator.

On an input like `a<NUL><NUL>b<NUL>c<NUL>`, `readarray -td '' array` gives `array=(a '' b c)`, while `array=("${(@0)$(cat)}")` gives `array=(a '' b c '')` with a generally unwanted empty trailing element. It can be removed with `array[-1]=()`.

NUL-delimited lists are often used to store file paths though, so removing *all* empty elements as `array=(${(0)"$(grep -rlZ pattern .)"})` does is an easy way to avoid the problem.

Another noteworthy difference with bash's `readarray` is that in `array=("${(@f)$(cmd)}")`, the exit status of `cmd` is preserved (contrary to with bash's `readarray -t array < <(cmd)` equivalent).

Comment: `$(< /dev/stdin)`  is wrong on Linux and cygwin at least. Use `$(cat)` instead. Beware command substitution strips all trailing newline characters, so trailing empty lines if any will be removed.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - maybe you're getting confused between shells and operating systems/subsystems. I can't test Cygwin, but I tested this on multiple *nix, the key component here is `zsh`.  Shells are responsible for expansion and redirection rules such as these.  It's correct that trailing (empty) newlines are stripped.

Comment: it's covered in dozen of Q&A's here, opening /dev/stdin on Linux / cygwin opens the file opened on the fd anew, it's not like a dup() like in other systems, so it fails on sockets for instance, and for regular files (or seekable files in general), it would read them from the beginning instead of from wherever stdin currently points in. For those, it would also not consume the input (not for pipes or ttys... obviously). See for instance [Bash function that accepts input from parameter or pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/607547)

Comment: Ah, I get you, so for `/dev/stdin` it's not going to work, but for a regular file it's ok.  Apologies, I was working on the assumption that `/dev/stdin` is handled as a regular file.  I didn't get the differentiation you were making in the original comment.

Comment: Updated the answer. @StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - do you happen to have a succinct reference we can link to in the answer to help anyone holding the same assumption as I did?

Comment: The link I gave above is not so bad. See if a search for `user:22565 linux fd pointed`  reveals better ones.

Comment: Should be `$(cat)`, not `$(cat /dev/stdin)` which has the same problem as `$(< /dev/stdin)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138143/discussion-between-ocodo-and-stephane-chazelas).

Comment: Might be worth noting that `f` is short for `ps[\n]`, `0` for `ps[\0]` and can specify arbitrary separator with `s[sep]` (which can be more than one byte contrary to with bash's `readarray -d`)

Comment: Add an edit please, I'll be back at the machine tomorrow morning (on phone)

Comment: `$(<&0)` also appears to read from `stdin`. Don't know if it has any advantage over `$(cat)`. cc:@StéphaneChazelas

Comment: @Gairfowl - so the whole "redundant use of `cat`" thing is simply noting the difference of using builtins, redirects etc. vs an external executable (in this case `cat`)

Answer (score 1):

There is one for zsh called [`mapfile`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fmapfile-Module), but it's a [module](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html) and must be loaded to use, and it's not a function unlike `readarray`.

```
zmodload zsh/mapfile
filename='...'
filelines=("${(@f)mapfile[$filename]}")
```

The purpose of the `(@f)` is the same as with the other answer here, and that is to split the contents of the file on newline.